# Failed to convert []interface{} to []byte: "interface {} is []interface [], not []uint8"

Tags: json, go

I am parsing large JSON file and I need parse its sub-object `items`.
You can see that `items` is in type `[]interface{}`:
[image]

I succeed to parse the first object `map[]string]interface{}` but after that I am trying to parse `pods["items"]` which is in type `[]interface{}` and I covnert it to `[]byte` for the `json.Unmarshal` function and it failed with:

> interface {} is []interface [], not []uint8

This is the code to reproduce:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var mytest string = `
{
   "kind":"PodList",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{
     
   },
   "items":[{
         "metadata":{
            "name":"super-user-pod5551",
            "namespace":"kube-system",
            "selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/super-user-pod5551",
            "uid":"fe9cf599-6e82-4a1b-8db5-5e319a58e1da"
         },
         "spec":{
            "volumes":[
               {
                  "name":"bootstrap-signer-token-dmp5q",
                  "secret":{
                     "secretName":"bootstrap-signer-token-dmp5q",
                     "defaultMode":420
                  }
               }
            ],
            "containers":[
               {
                  "name":"redis",
                  "image":"busybox:1.28",
                  "resources":{
                     
                  },
                  "volumeMounts":[
                     {
                        "name":"bootstrap-signer-token-dmp5q",
                        "readOnly":true,
                        "mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
                     }
                  ],
                  "terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log",
                  "terminationMessagePolicy":"File",
                  "imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent",
                  "securityContext":{
                     "capabilities":{
                        "add":[
                           "SYS_TIME"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            ],
            "restartPolicy":"Always",
            "terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30,
            "schedulerName":"default-scheduler"
         },
         "status":{
            "phase":"Failed",
            "message":"The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. ",
            "reason":"Evicted",
            "startTime":"2020-05-10T11:13:33Z"
         }
      }
    ]
}
`


func main(){

    //var pods interface{}
    var pods map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(mytest), &pods)
    fmt.Println(err)
    //var spec map[string]interface{}
    //err = json.Unmarshal(byte(pods["items"]), &pods["items"])
    var items []interface{}

    err = json.Unmarshal(pods["items"].([]byte), &items)
    fmt.Println(err)

}
```

[Link to GoPlayground](https://play.golang.org/p/Mpg-AfT7Ee4).

Comment: The error is pretty explicit and clear. What is your question?

Comment: Because I don't understand the error, I tried to change it to `[]uint8` and it still doesn't work. Why attacking instead of trying to help newbie?

Comment: like the error states, `pods["items"]` is a `[]interface{}`. It's never going to be `[]byte`, because you've already unmarshaled the json. Why are you trying to unmarshal again?

Comment: Because after I unmarshal it, I can't access to `pods["items"][0]`

Comment: You can't index an `interface{}`, you need to assert the correct type (which is `[]interface{}`, as you've shown already).

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go which explain how Go's type system works.

Comment: @Volker I read https://tour.golang.org/basics/11 I didn't teach me anything new or something that can help me solve my issue.

Comment: @JimB But I already tried to assert `[]interface{}` and it doesn't accept it

Comment: yes it does: https://play.golang.org/p/YBoHBhfKN5i

Comment: @E235 it's recommended to use proper struct types that match the structure of the json, if possible. Avoid `map[string]interface{}` if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I read "Arbitrary objects and arrays" in [this](https://yourbasic.org/golang/json-example/) blog, I understood how to do it.

Like @Steven Eckhoff mentioned, I need to move the `map[string]interface{}` object to a variable and then run over it with key and value, I can check each value by its type and iterate over these objects.

Here is the example of the main code with the solution:

```
func main(){

    var pods interface{}
    //var pods PodList
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(mytest), &pods)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    data := pods.(map[string]interface{})
    for k, v := range data {
        switch v := v.(type) {
        case string:
            fmt.Println(k, v, "(string)")
        case float64:
            fmt.Println(k, v, "(float64)")
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Println(k, "(array):")
            for _, u := range v {
                //fmt.Println("    ", i, u)
                u := u.(map[string]interface{})
                for a,b := range u {
                    if a == "metadata" {
                        b := b.(map[string]interface{})
                        for c,e := range b {
                            if c == "name" {
                                fmt.Println(e)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //fmt.Println("    ", a, b)
                }
            }
        default:
            fmt.Println(k, v, "(unknown)")
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
kind PodList (string)
apiVersion v1 (string)
metadata map[] (unknown)
items (array):
super-user-pod5551
```

The best way is to define `struct` for the object but I was interested to understand how to do it without `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you aren't doing a type conversion as you claim. You are instead doing a type assertion.

Since `pods["items"]` is a `[]interface{}` you would first need each interface to have a concrete type of `[]byte` and do the assertion on each and collect those into a `[]byte` before you could execute the unmarshal.

Ultimately you should create a `struct` that you can simply unmarshal to and that will greatly simplify your code.

As others have said the fact that you are unmarshalling twice should be an indication that there is a better way.

Comment: But I can't call each interface inside pods["items"] because I can't range over data of `interface{}`

Comment: You would need to do `items := pods["items"].([]interface{})`. This will quickly get out of hand though. You should really just create a `struct` that you can unmarshal to and you will avoid this mess.